# Ajax handler class does not reach my url address

Tags: javascript, razor

im new in js,i have created a function and named it ajax handler,what its suppose to it it get the url,get the parameters and return result,please let me know where the problem is coming from,:

in the js file here is the function :

```
function AjaxHandler(fromDate,toDate,_clickedTurbine,_url) {
    var finalresult;
    var ajaxCallResult;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: _url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 
            "dtFrom": fromDate, 
            "dtTo": toDate, 
            "name": _clicked
        }),
        success: function (result) {
        ajaxCallResult = result;          
    }});
    return {
        finalresult: ajaxCallResult
    }
 }
```

in my view i do like this,but it never reaches my controller to get data and return:

```
var s=AjaxHandler(dtDrpVals.fromDate, dtDrpVals.toDate, _clicked, "@Url.Action("faultstatistics","Dashbrd")");
```

Comment: what is `_clicked` ? please create a snipet so we can run the code in a context

Comment: @BogdanM. clicked event of chart,when i click on the bar returns me the name of bar

Comment: i think i found it,i should make  async: false,